# Troubleshooting Multiple Errors: PCIe, NVIDIA, Bluetooth, and Wireless Adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, bluetooth

**Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop**.

Hardware: Acer Aspire A315-53G RAM: 4gb CPU:Intel® Core™ i3-7020U × 4 GPU:Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2F) / Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2F) and a nvidia geforce mx130

Summary:
I'm facing multiple errors on my computer, including PCIe port issues, a failed NVIDIA device query, Bluetooth plugin initialization errors, and problems with my wireless network adapter. I need help troubleshooting these errors and finding possible solutions.

Details and Research:

```
PCIe Port Errors:
    The system logs indicate "AER: Error of this Agent is reported first" messages for PCIe ports.
    Research indicates that Advanced Error Reporting (AER) is a feature in PCIe systems that helps detect and report errors related to PCIe devices.
    Troubleshooting could involve checking for loose connections, updating BIOS, or checking for compatibility issues between PCIe devices and motherboard.

Failed NVIDIA Device Query:
    The error "Failed to query NVIDIA devices" is reported for the "nvidia-persistenced" service.
    Research suggests this could be due to incorrect driver installation or missing device files.
    Troubleshooting might involve reinstalling NVIDIA drivers, checking for NVIDIA device files in /dev directory, or verifying if NVIDIA modules are loaded.

Bluetooth Plugin and Mode Errors:
    The Bluetooth daemon reports "Failed to init" errors for vcp, mcp, and bap plugins, and also "Failed to set mode."
    Research indicates these errors could result from plugin conflicts or incorrect configurations.
    Troubleshooting may involve checking the Bluetooth daemon's configuration files, ensuring all required plugins are available, and restarting the Bluetooth service.

Atheros Wireless Adapter Errors:
    Multiple AER errors are reported for the "ath10k_pci" driver for the wireless network adapter.
    Research suggests these errors might be caused by driver issues or hardware problems.
    Troubleshooting could include updating the wireless adapter driver, checking for firmware updates, or inspecting the physical condition of the adapter.
```

What I've Tried:

```
Provide information about any steps already taken to address the issues or attempted solutions.
Mention any relevant actions such as system updates, driver reinstalls, or hardware checks.
```

Any help or guidance on resolving these errors would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: its Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: the Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop if you want to know my laptop is a Acer Aspire A315-53G RAM: 4gb CPU:Intel® Core™ i3-7020U × 4  GPU:Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2F) / Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2F) and a nvidia geforce mx130

Comment: ok architecture/hardware 64-bit

Comment: its x86-64/AMD64